# arm and disarm an alarm system

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Before I go to bed I always **arm** my alarm system in Home Mode.

When I get up in the morning I **disarm** the alarm system.

Do native speakers use 'arm' and 'disarm' in this context or would it sound odd? I found a few examples where they were used when I searched for the right word to use on Google. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'd more likely use ***set*** and ***turn off***. Disarming sounds more like heavy-duty military stuff to me.

Comment: I think they sound fine.  They are the terms that vendors use, e.g. ["This video covers the most common ways of arming your ADEMCO by Honeywell home security system"](https://www.protection1.com/support/technical/how-to/ademco/arm/) and ["The system can be remotely disarmed using the website or app."](https://help.myalarmcenter.com/knowledge/disarm-the-system-remotely/)

Comment: I used to have an alarm system which incorporated a recorded voice saying "System is set/unset". Then it was changed for a version that said it was arming/disarming. The current version doesn't speak to me! (I think I preferred the first one!)

Comment: arm and disarm is not accurate here. It sounds like Spanish. Turn on/turn off//set/turn off

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could say "arm" and "disarm". However, those words carry connotations of weaponry. (Saying that a person is "armed" usually means that he or she has a weapon. That is probably why FF said in a comment that "disarming sounds more like heavy-duty military stuff to me.")

Instead, in the evening you could say that you "turned on" or "set" the alarm. In the morning, you could say that you "turned off" or "disabled" the alarm. (Other words are possible, too; these are just some common examples.)

Comment: I "set" and "unset" mine.

Answer (score 1):

You certain can use 'arm' and 'disarm'. I have used them myself in general conversation. I suspect I would favour 'set' and 'turned off'. If the situation was slightly different, for example talking to a colleague about a workplace alarm, the use 'arm' and 'disarm' would be more likely. This perhaps implies, that for me, 'arm' and 'disarm' are more formal terms (than say 'set' and 'turned off')